# UICollectionView content not recognized (when searching)

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I am new in Swift , I have a problem with my CollectionView. I have 2 custom cells in a CollectionView. The first cell, say `cell` and the second `cellOcc`, where `cell` is empty table and the `cellOcc` is occupied table. It works normal when app is starting but it goes weird when I try to search them (the content is not properly in their position). Below is my code, any suggestions and help will be helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredSearchDataTable = filterArray(filteredDataTable, keywords: "tischnr", searchStr: searchText)
    tableCollectionView.reloadData()
}

..........

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count:Int = 0

    if(searchBarIsActive) {
        count = filteredSearchDataTable.count
    }
    else{
        count = filteredDataTable.count
    }

    return count

//        return max(filteredDataTable.count, 2)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell: TableCollectionViewCell = tableCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emptyTable", for: indexPath) as! TableCollectionViewCell
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    if (searchBarIsActive) {
        currTable = (filteredSearchDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyHashable: Any])
        cell.labelTableNr.text = (String(currTable["tischnr"] as! Int))
    }
    else {
        currTable = (filteredDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyHashable: Any])
        cell.labelTableNr.text = (String(currTable["tischnr"] as! Int))
        currRechnr = getJSONArrayIndex(filteredDataBill, name: "tischnr", o: ((currTable["tischnr"] as! Int)))

        if self.selectedIndex.index(of: indexPath as NSIndexPath) == nil {
            //
        } else {
            //
        }
    }

    var rechnrValue = 0

    if currRechnr >= 0 {
        rechnrValue = ((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any])["rechnr"] as! Int)
        if (rechnrValue != 0) {
            let cellOcc : TableOccupiedCollectionViewCell = tableCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "occupiedTable", for: indexPath) as! TableOccupiedCollectionViewCell

            cellOcc.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cellOcc.layer.cornerRadius = 5

            cellOcc.tableNrOccLabel.text = ((filteredDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["bezeich"] as! String)
            cellOcc.paxOccLabel.text = (String((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["belegung"] as! Int))

            cellOcc.guestNameLabel.text = ((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["bilname"] as! String)
            cellOcc.amountLabel.text = (String((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["saldo"] as! Int))

            return cellOcc
            }
        else {
            return cell
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. In all my func CollectionView, its always have two case (searchBarActive & normal). I put the logic to both of case. So below my final code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: TableCollectionViewCell = tableCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emptyTable", for: indexPath) as! TableCollectionViewCell
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    if (searchBarIsActive) {
        currTable = (filteredSearchDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyHashable: Any])
        cell.labelTableNr.text = (String(currTable["tischnr"] as! Int))

        currRechnr = getJSONArrayIndex(filteredDataBill, name: "tischnr", o: ((currTable["tischnr"] as! Int)))
        var rechnrValue = 0

        if currRechnr >= 0 {
            rechnrValue = ((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any])["rechnr"] as! Int)
            if (rechnrValue != 0) {
                let cellOcc : TableOccupiedCollectionViewCell = tableCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "occupiedTable", for: indexPath) as! TableOccupiedCollectionViewCell

                cellOcc.layer.borderWidth = 1
                cellOcc.layer.cornerRadius = 5

                cellOcc.tableNrOccLabel.text = ((filteredSearchDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["bezeich"] as! String)
                cellOcc.paxOccLabel.text = (String((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["belegung"] as! Int))

                cellOcc.guestNameLabel.text = ((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["bilname"] as! String)
                cellOcc.amountLabel.text = (String((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["saldo"] as! Int))

                return cellOcc
            }
            else {
                return cell
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        currTable = (filteredDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyHashable: Any])
        cell.labelTableNr.text = (String(currTable["tischnr"] as! Int))

        currRechnr = getJSONArrayIndex(filteredDataBill, name: "tischnr", o: ((currTable["tischnr"] as! Int)))
        var rechnrValue = 0

        if currRechnr >= 0 {
            rechnrValue = ((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any])["rechnr"] as! Int)
            if (rechnrValue != 0) {
                let cellOcc : TableOccupiedCollectionViewCell = tableCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "occupiedTable", for: indexPath) as! TableOccupiedCollectionViewCell

                cellOcc.layer.borderWidth = 1
                cellOcc.layer.cornerRadius = 5

                cellOcc.tableNrOccLabel.text = ((filteredDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["bezeich"] as! String)
                cellOcc.paxOccLabel.text = (String((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["belegung"] as! Int))

                cellOcc.guestNameLabel.text = ((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["bilname"] as! String)
                cellOcc.amountLabel.text = (String((filteredDataBill[currRechnr] as! [AnyHashable: Any]) ["saldo"] as! Int))

                return cellOcc
            }
            else {
                return cell
            }
        }
}
```